# Statistical sampling for auditing

Tags: sampling

I have a team with agents that I have to audit their services (which has a standardized rating system that I follow).

There are 11 guys that I need to audit and each of them work a different amount of cases per week. I.e.

```
Agent   Cases worked
Guy A       93
Guy B       53
Guy C       81
Guy D       111
...         ...
Guy K       73
```

I was reading about [statistical sampling](http://web.csulb.edu/~msaintg/ppa696/696sampl.htm), but didn't figure how to make an effective way to split my work and still have a significant confidence in my audits.

Should I use something like [Sample Size Calculator](http://www.surveysystem.com/sscalc.htm) for each of them? Or is there another systematic approach that works better for this scenario?

I want to have their average scores per week but I am not able to investigate all cases.

Comment: Does the number of cases worked have an impact on the rating / performance? As in; agents that work more cases probably have higher (or lower) ratings than agents with fewer cases? Also, are all cases independent?

Comment: You audit one of their cases and get a rating? How do you use this rating in the end? Is there some kind of "passing grade"?

Comment: @Sven I rate each case based on a 10 score system. The amount of cases worked does not impact the agent score. Their score is currently based only on the average score for the audited cases. ( I am asking here because I don't want to be unfair with the sample size for each)

Comment: @Andrea the rating is a 10 ten point, there is no set passing grade, but the one with the highest overall score gets a bonus.

Comment: Alright cool. I think the easiest thing to do is simply rate the same number of cases for every worker, where you pick the cases randomly. If you want to be most efficient in finding the best agent (either with fixed number of audits or with a fixed level of confidence), then you should look into the pure-exploration bandit problem.